# AHK (Auto Hot Key) Launch calculator using if/else

Tags: autohotkey

**AHK 2.0**

I am new to AHK and learning how to use IF/ELSE on pressing a hot key.

I am able to launch/activate calculator using below commands.

```
#HotIf WinExist("Calculator")
#c::WinActivate
#HotIf not WinExist("Calculator")
#c::Run "calc"
```

However I am trying to achieve the same using if/else using below commands but getting an error.

```
#c::
If not WinExist("Calculator")
{
    Run "calc" ; launch calculator
}
else
{
    WinActivate ; activate calculator
}
```

Error

```
Error: Hotkey or hotstring is missing its opening brace.

Line:   7
File:   C:\Users\srk\Documents\AutoHotkey\SRK_AHK.ahk

The script was not reloaded; the old version will remain in effect.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AHK v2 you need to enclose the [hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm#Intro)'s body in braces, if the hotkey needs to execute more than one line. The braces serve to define a function body for the hotkey.

In the [if statements](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/If.htm) you need the braces only if the statement owns more than one line.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

#c::
{
    If not WinExist("Calculator")
        Run "calc" ; launch calculator
    else
        WinActivate ; activate calculator
}
```

Comment: What does below statement do?  Is it required or just a comment?

`#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0`

Comment: See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/_Requires.htm